# WIndows login exception dialog box - Element not found

Tags: windows-10

I log into a windows box and this dialog box pops up.

[image]

Why is it and how can I remove it?

Comment: what windows box?

Comment: 'what windows box?' - It is just colloquial english to mean a Windows PC. The question is labelled 'Windows 10'.

Comment: The word "box" has many meanings relevant to technology and computers. As does the uncapitalized "window". It was not clear what you were saying, and clarity is important when communicating issues for the purpose of solving them.

Answer (score 0):

The message window is telling you pretty much exactly what's going on: Apple Mobile Device program is messed up.

Standard procedures will involve repairing the software (probably iTunes), or telling the Apple Mobile Device tool not to start when Windows starts.